# Help understanding how to remove faucet with perpendicular pipe sticking out

Tags: faucet

My mom's kitchen sink is very old and the faucets were leaking so I tried to help her replace them.

[image]

I am not sure where to proceed from here. I believe that the attachment nut cannot be removed because it would not fit over the part of the pipe that is sticking out perpendicular to the rest (I do not know what it is called). I'm also very concerned that the faucets are too old and there is too much rust for the nut to be removed. How should I move forward with this?

[image]

This is the top of the sink, I have no idea what model the faucets are but my mom said that she believes they're Pfister.

Comment: Can you take and post a picture higher up from the side of the fitting in question?  I cannot tell exactly what you have there.

Comment: Sometimes when a new sink and faucet are installed at the same time people install the faucet on the sink *before* the sink is put in place. It is a lot easier to install the faucet on the sink when that is done, but it is possible to install a faucet with an extra dishwasher Tee that could not be removed very easily without removing the sink. I am not saying that is the case with your sink, but just that it could have been done that way. So do not assume that the sink was put in first and then the faucet installed with the sink in place.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should remove the faucet handles and take a look from above. Most likely you remove a small cap at "A" and reveal a screw that when taken out permits the faucet handle to be lifted off.

[image]

Once removed there may be a nut or ring clip that is normally covered by the "B" skirt of the faucet handle. Removing that nut or clip ring would allow the rest of the faucet assembly to drop below the sink.

The center water spout part of the faucet assembly most likely does need to be freed from below and then pulled up through the top of the sink. You would would need to take apart that 4 way pipe fitting assembly that all the hoses are attached to and then use a basin wrench (as suggested in another answer) to loosen the large nut up around the center hole part of the sink.

Note that if the faucet units have ring clips it may be necessary to also loosen their large nuts from underneath so that the ring clip can then be removed. Usually when these types of faucets are initially installed the large nut is pre- threaded  down on the unit toward the right angle port where the hose attaches.Then the thing is shoved up through the hole, the clip attached, and then the nut underneath is tightened up to the underside of the sink to secure the valve unit in place.

Answer (score 0):

### Looks like you need a basin wrench

The top image shows a brass tee joint. It looks like you've already removed the pipe that was attached to the center of the tee but find there's no good way to get at the rest of the tee with a standard crescent wrench. What you need is a basin wrench. There are fairly easy to find at the hardware store.

Have a look at this video for instructions on how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3mibmhjwHA